# How to style all edges in a tikz-qtree as arrows?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-qtree

I'd like the edges in my tikz-qtree to be painted as arrows (pointing to the child node).

How can this be done? I found a lot of questions here about how to add addtional edges, lines or arcs, but none about how to draw the edges in a tikz-qtree as arrows instead of plain lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `edge from parent` style. A compete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzset{edge from parent/.append style={->}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.A
  [.B ]
  [.C ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Changing to `latex` arrow tips and adding red color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzset{edge from parent/.append style={->,>=latex,red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.A
  [.B ]
  [.C ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, so simple and yet I managed to look around for an hour without finding it. Thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: Can this be extended to work for specified nodes only?